# What's the use of so file and how to include the c++ libraries within the so file in android studio?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio

I'm trying to run DNN with the help of [MNN](https://github.com/alibaba/MNN) in android studio project.

### What I Do:

- I create a Native C++ project in android studio.
- I have built `libMNN.so` according to the document of MNN, and place it in the directory `app/arm64-v8a/libMNN.so`
- I have changed the `app/build.gradle` as follows

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.mymnn'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mymnn"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.18.1'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

- Then I can see `app/jniLibs` in Android View in android studio. It seems like I have import so file successfully.
- I notice that in the MNN demo project they include MNN files by `#include <MNN/expr/Module.hpp>` rather than `#include "MNN/expr/Module.hpp"`, **so I think `MNN/expr/Module.hpp` should be compiled in the so file `libMNN.so`**. However, I cannot import it by `#include <MNN/expr/Module.hpp>` in my `src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp` file.

### What I Wonder

As a beginner for both C++ and android project, I want to know

- The usage of so file (does it provide some APIs that I can include in C++ header files?)
- Does `#include <MNN/expr/Module.hpp>` includes `Module.hpp` from so file? If yes how can I inlcude it in my project?

Comment: Maybe you want to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639655/what-is-the-actual-use-of-so-file-in-android)

Comment: The library contains the implementation, the headers are the interface to that implementation and are separate from it, you need to configure their location separately

Comment: @AlanBirtles  thanks, does that mean I need to add the header files of MNN into my project (in directory `cpp/include`), then modify `app/build.gradle` or `CMakeLists.txt` to tell the project to import these header files when building the project?

Comment: I suggest you follow a cmake tutorial

Comment: @AlanBirtles I mean, I have already improt so file (the implementation) in my project, so I need to import the headers files now (the interface), right?